# What is the reason to put a tilde between "p."/"page" and the number?

Tags: spacing, biblatex

When citing a page, the Biblatex manual puts a tilde between "p."/"page" and the number:

```
\footcite[Cp.][p.~23]{Smith-2013}
```

Why? I actually have never really googled for this and now that I have, I am unable to find any good results or think of one.

I recall that I used

```
\footcite[Cp.][p. 23]{Smith-2013}
```

a couple of times and I didn't have any problems with the space disappearing or anything. Then I converted back to the tilde method just for the sake of it but did not inquire about it.

Comment: ~ is a non-breakable space.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am aware of that and this was not my question.

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: Well, if the space cannot be broken up, the p/page and the number stick together on one line

Comment: If this question is really about `biblatex`, *do not* write `\footcite[Cp.][p.~23]{Smith-2013}` but `\footcite[Cp.][23]{Smith-2013}`. If the `postnote` only contains a number (actually, more specifically, something `biblatex` recognises as page range), it adds the "page"/"p" prefix and an appropriate space itself.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for reminding me, I just got used to the `p.~`-method over the years. Besides, wouldn't that be problematic for what the protected space is making it avoid? Or does biblatex avoid line breaks for the postnote automatically?

Comment: `biblatex` automatically adds a `\ppspace` between the page prefix ("p."/"page") and the actual page number. `\ppspace` defaults to `\addnbspace`, a non-breaking space. (All this can be found in `biblatex2.sty`.)

Comment: Wohoo, another thing learned today. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` is a non-breakable space so no line break will separate the "p." and the number. Not using it might result (if the string "p. #" happens to be close to a lind end) in the string "p." and the number on different lines (even on different pages if "p." is close to a page break) which is not correct.

This is a case of a general rule: when an object is mentioned together with a number (for example, when one cross-references a figure in the form "Figure 5 on page 234"), the object and its associated number must not be separated by a line break. Thus, one has to introduce non-breakable spaces at the proper locations: `Figure~\ref{fig:image} on page~\pageref{fig:image}`.

Comment: Really, that's it? In the case there was a line break in the footnote, I assume the majority of times the page reference isn't broken. As in, never. I never had that problem. But then... my thought was probably based on pointless egotistical thinking.

Comment: @henry The fact that it has not occurred to you up to this moment doesn't rules out the possibility of it happening to someone at some time :)

Comment: Very true... :)

Comment: @henry The problem is not so much if you use this in a footnote (`\footcite`), but if you use `\cite`, `\parencite` or `\textcite`, "p. #" might well hit the end of a line.

Comment: My first comment here seems out of place now. When I posted it there was just the first sentence written in the reply. @moewe that is a good point.

Answer (score 3):

Two things: line breaks and spacing. Without the tilde, TeX an break between 'p.' (or page) and '23' in the example. It's normally considered 'bad style' to have a break here or in any case where you have 'Thing X'-type links. In the specific case of `p.`, as you are using a full stop (period) preceded by a lower case letter, TeX will treat this as an end-of-sentence and may insert extra space (depending on whether `\frenchspacing` is active). To prevent this you certainly need `p.\ 23` even if you want to allow a line break (not a good idea).

Note that depending on the exact nature of your input you may not notice the first issue (of not occurring at a break) or the second (if `\frenchspacing` is set).

Comment: Interesting. Also, I wasn't aware that it was 'bad style'.